# How to get two (or more) rows into individual arrays providing individual access to each rows column

Tags: mysql, perl, multidimensional-array, rows

I have been struggling with this for 16 hours straight and I am at my wits end. I have read all manpages, attempted to make my own, tried several examples and modded many to no avail.

All I want to do is grab some lines from my DB and be able to access each rows variables (column data) individually.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
    use strict;
    use CGI;
    use CGI ':standard';
    use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
    print CGI::header(-expires => '-1d');
    use DBI;
    $|=1;

use vars qw($getstate $hookup $query $results $city $state $pages $category $lastupdate $progress $actual $city1 $state1 $pages1 $category1 $lastupdate1 $progress1 $actual1);


    $getstate = 'Arizona'; ## actually comes in from a query

    ##$hookup is returned from a sub with database credentials
   $query = $hookup->prepare(qq{SELECT `city`,`state`,`pages`,`category`,`lastupdate`,`progress`,`actual` FROM `statesettings` WHERE `pages` > `progress` AND `state` LIKE ? ORDER BY `lastupdate` ASC LIMIT 2}); 
    $query->bind_param(1, "%$getstate%");
    $query->execute() or die "Query did not execute";

    ## I HAVE TRIED all kinds of ways to fetch data! fetchall_arrayref() fetchrow_array() and dozens upon dozens of attempts.

    while ($results = $query->fetchrow_hashref) {
    $city = $results->{city};
    $pages = $results->{pages};
    $category = $results->{category};
    $lastupdate = $results->{lastupdate};
    $progress = $results->{progress};
    $actual = $results->{actual};
    #####################
    }## end WHILE
    $query->finish;
    $hookup->disconnect;
```

Which, in above for example, I can only figure out how to access one row.

But I want something like: (obviously set up for number of rows I asked for)

```
$city = $arr[0]['city']; #city from row 0
$city1 = $arr[1]['city']; #city from row 1
```

OR WHATEVER allows me to get each rows column data individually for use further in!

I was actually successful with a huge piece of code I wrote that pushed all data into an array with a ':' dividing the rows which I split later on then looped each one. Was prob a great example of how to get my result with the most possible code. I know what I want to do is "built in" but, I just don't possess the brain power. 
I feel completely brain dead in that I cannot figure this out after so many hours.
Too close to see possibly?

I would like a little explanation along with any sample code so, I can learn / understand the mechanics. Thanks so much for your guidance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write:

```
my @arr;
while ($results = $query->fetchrow_hashref)
{
  push @arr, $results;
}
$query->finish;
$hookup->disconnect;
```

and then perform any other assignments you want:

```
my $city = $arr[0]->{'city'}; # city from first row
my $city1 = $arr[1]->{'city'}; # city from second row
```

or:

```
my @all_cities = map { $_->{'city'} } @arr;

my $city = $all_cities[0]; # city from first row
my $city1 = $all_cities[1]; # city from second row
```

Comment: Thank you! Both worked perfectly and exactly what I wanted! Can I have some of your D.N.A.?

Comment: How would I do something like: my ($city,$state,$pages,$category,$lastupdate,$progress,$actual) = @arr[row1]; AND  my ($city1,$state1,$pages1,$category1,$lastupdate1,$progress1,$actual1) = @arr[row2];

Comment: @Jim_Bo: Each element of `@arr` is a *hash*-ref, not an *array*-ref, so the data-points are not ordered. There's no sense in which `$arr[0]->{'city'}` comes "before" `$arr[0]->{'state'}`. The closest you could come is `my ($city,$state,$pages,$category,$lastupdate,$progress,$actual) = @{$arr[0]}{qw/city state pages category lastupdate progress actual/};` . . . but anyway, why you *want* that? Why do you want a separate variable-name for each field in each row? That doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Well, instead of going down the line with my $city = $cities[0]->{'city'}; I figured assigning (each var) = array[x] would be easier? I do need each piece of data from each row assigned so I can use them in various places afterward. I tried your my ($city,$state,$pages,$category,$lastupdate,$progress,$actual) = @{$arr[0]}; an then a print $state but, returned nothing. I guess I need more help there.

Comment: @Jim_Bo: You misread/miscopied my code. It didn't end with `rr[0]}`, but with `al/};`.

Comment: I tried my ($city,$state,$pages,$category,$lastupdate,$progress,$actual) = @{$cities[0]}{qw/city state pages category lastupdate progress actual/};
my ($city1,$state1,$pages1,$category1,$lastupdate1,$progress1,$actual1) = @{$cities[1]}{qw/city1 state1 pages1 category1 lastupdate1 progress1 actual1/};
print qq~category1 $category1<br />~;
print qq~category $category <br >~; But only $category printed no $category1 ???

Comment: Your second statement needs to have `qw/city state ... progress actual/` (like the first one), *not* `qw/city1 state1 ... progress1 actual1/`. (If you're not familiar with the `qw//` notation, it's just a convenient way to write a list of barewords. `{qw/city state ... progress actual/}` is the same as `{'city', 'state', ..., 'progress' 'actual'}`. In this case, it contains your hash-keys.)

Comment: Also tried my ($city,$state,$pages,$category,$lastupdate,$progress,$actual,$city1,$state1,$pages1,$category1,$lastupdate1,$progress1,$actual1) = @{$cities[0]}{qw/city state pages category lastupdate progress actual city1 state1 pages1 category1 lastupdate1 progress1 actual1/};

Comment: I SEE says the blind man!!!THANK YOU! Perhaps I need some rest as that was pretty obvious. I honestlt appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

```
my $res_arrayref;
while ($results = $query->fetchrow_hashref) {
... your code...
push @{$res_arrayref}, $result;
}    

...later...
$res_arrayref->[0]->{city};
```

Comment: What is ... your code ...? I just removed that. Also changed $result to $results but, still could not get it to return anything.